# BindingAdapter with multiple parameters not working

Tags: android, data-binding

Just one parameter, works well.

But with two parameter, occurs an error.

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'date' with parameter type java.util.Date on android.widget.TextView.

This is `BindingAdapter` method.

```
@BindingAdapter("format", "date")
 fun dateToStringWithFormat(view : TextView, format : String, date: Date) {
   view.text = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).format(date)
```

}

This is `.xml` has `TextView`.
`diary.date` is `Date` type.

```
  <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/text_diary"
        dateFormat="MMM" //format
        date="@{diary.date}" //date
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:padding = "10dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
    />
```

I tired `clean Build -> rebuild`.

Erase `.idea`, `.gradle`.
But still not working.

Comment: I had the same problem and just solved it, check out the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278287/bindingadapter-doesnt-work-with-databinding/52278618#52278618