# BindingAdapter doesn't work with DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-binding-adapter

I've got a button:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:binding="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.MyViewModel" />
    </data>
    <Button
                binding:singleParameterString="test"
                binding:firstStringParameter="@{vm.userName}"
    .../>
...
```

The BindingAdapter looks as follows:

```
@BindingAdapter("binding:singleParameterString", "binding:firstStringParameter")
        fun setFormattedString(btn: Button, singleParameterString: String, firstStringParameter: String) {
            btn.text = String.format(singleParameterString, firstStringParameter)
        }
```

This doesn't work, it gives the following error: "Cannot find the setter for attribute 'binding:firstStringParameter' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.Button.". 
However, if I change  `binding:firstStringParameter="@{vm.userName}"` to, for example,  `binding:firstStringParameter="my lovely string"` this will work.

The userName in the ViewModel is `val userName: String = "my name"` and if I try `android:text="@{vm.userName}"` that works. 
So the problem is in the databinding. I've got another project where I used the same code and it works... Sounds like a bug in the databinding/adaperbinding framework, but maybe someone came across this problem?

P.S.
I also tried `binding:firstStringParameter="@{` `+ vm.userName}"`, did not work.

By looking at the autogenerated Binding class I discovered a very strange code:

```
blah.setFormattedString(this.mboundView1, (java.lang.String)null, javaLangStringVmUserName);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, the library is broken. I found a solution.
It will only work if both parameters are either hardcoded strings OR are passed from the ViewModel.

So, that

```
binding:firstStringParameter="@{vm.
binding:singleParameterString="@{vm.test}"
```

and that works:

```
 binding:firstStringParameter="userName"
 binding:singleParameterString="test"
```

, but this doesn't work:

```
 binding:firstStringParameter="@{vm.userName}"
 binding:singleParameterString="test"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for this problem:

```
binding:firstStringParameter="@{notification.user.pic}"
binding:singleParameterString="@{`test`}"
```